# How to remain KeyListener Images on JFrame after pressing a new Key

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist, keylistener

I'm completely new to Java and my project is to make a postcard generator with the keyboard.
My problem now is that I don't know how to make the images stay in the Frame when a new Key is pressed. Im sure I need an ArrayList but I don't know where it belongs in the code.
I would appreciate any help :)

```
public class Funktionier extends Canvas implements KeyListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2576012469492443014L;
public JFrame frame;
private Image []pngs;
private int currentImage; 
private Random random;
private int x;
private int y;

public Funktionier(int width, int height)
{
    pngs = new Image[26]; 
    for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
        try {
            pngs[i] = ImageIO.read(new File("./res/JAVA-"+(char) ('A'+i)+".png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    frame = new JFrame ();
    JTextField field = new JTextField (30); 
    field.setBounds(219, 10, 437, 20); 
    frame.add(field);
    
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Deine Karte");
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(width, height);   
    field.addKeyListener(this);  

    frame.add(this);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.requestFocus();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //currentImage = 0;
    random = new Random (); 
    randomXY ();
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
    new Funktionier (874,620);
}
public void randomXY () {
    x= random.nextInt(getWidth()-130); 
    y= random.nextInt(getHeight()-110); 
}
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(pngs[currentImage],  x,  y,  pngs[currentImage].getWidth(null),  pngs[currentImage].getHeight(null),  null);
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {  
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {    
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   
    if(e.getKeyChar() < 'a' || e.getKeyChar() > 'z') return; 
    currentImage= e.getKeyChar()-'a' ;          
    randomXY ();    
    repaint (); 
}
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could post a link to a ZIP file containing your 26 images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should draw on a `JPanel` and not a `Canvas` so make class `Funktionier` extend `JPanel` and not `Canvas`.

You should override method `paintComponent()` and not method `paint()`. The first thing you need to do in your overridden `paintComponent()` method is to call `super.paintComponent()`.

Each time `paintComponent()` is called, you need to draw **everything** because each time `paintComponent()` is called, you're starting with a blank `JPanel`. So don't just draw the "current" image. Also draw all the images you drew up to the current image.

Refer to [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and also [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

### EDIT

Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class Funktionier extends JPanel implements DocumentListener, Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4909941254467865823L;
    private static final Image[]  PNGS;
    private JFrame  frame;
    private List<ImagLocn>  imagesToDraw;
    private Random  rand;

    static {
        PNGS = new Image[26];
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            try {
                PNGS[i] = ImageIO.read(new File("JAVA-" + (char) ('A' + i) + ".png"));
            }
            catch (IOException xIo) {
                throw new RuntimeException(xIo);
            }
        }
    }

    public Funktionier(int width, int height) {
        imagesToDraw = new ArrayList<>();
        rand = new Random();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    }

    @Override // javax.swing.event.DocumentListener
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent docEvent) {
        if (docEvent.getLength() > 0) {
            Document doc = docEvent.getDocument();
            int length = doc.getLength();
            try {
                String text = doc.getText(0, length);
                text = text.strip();
                length = text.length();
                String lastLetter = text.substring(length - 1, length);
                int index = lastLetter.charAt(0) - 'A';
                if (index >= 0  &&  index < PNGS.length) {
                    imagesToDraw.add(new ImagLocn(PNGS[index],
                                                  rand.nextInt(getWidth()),
                                                  rand.nextInt(getHeight())));
                    repaint();
                }
            }
            catch (BadLocationException xBadLocation) {
                throw new RuntimeException(xBadLocation);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override // javax.swing.event.DocumentListener
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent docEvent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // javax.swing.event.DocumentListener
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent docEvent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    @Override // javax.swing.JComponent
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (ImagLocn il : imagesToDraw) {
            g.drawImage(il.getImage(), il.getX(), il.getY(), null);
        }
    }

    private JPanel createTextFieldPanel() {
        JPanel textFieldPanel = new JPanel();
        JTextField field = new JTextField(30);
        Document doc = field.getDocument();
        doc.addDocumentListener(this);
        if (doc instanceof AbstractDocument) {
            AbstractDocument absDoc = (AbstractDocument) doc;
            absDoc.setDocumentFilter(new DocuFltr());
        }
        textFieldPanel.add(field);
        return textFieldPanel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Deine Karte");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTextFieldPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Funktionier(500, 500));
    }
}

class DocuFltr extends DocumentFilter {

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass  fb,
                             int           offset,
                             String        string,
                             AttributeSet  attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (string.matches("^[A-Za-z]+$")) {
            fb.insertString(offset, string.toUpperCase(), attr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass  fb,
                        int           offset,
                        int           length,
                        String        text,
                        AttributeSet  attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        if (text.matches("^[A-Za-z]+$")) {
            fb.replace(offset, length, text.toUpperCase(), attrs);
        }
    }
}

class ImagLocn {
    private Image  image;
    private int  x;
    private int  y;

    public ImagLocn(Image img, int anX, int aY) {
        image = img;
        x = anX;
        y = aY;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Here is how it looks when I run the above code.

[image: Your card]

1. Refer to [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Don't use `setBounds()` to place your components on the screen. Use a layout manager. The default layout manager for the content pane of a `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`.
2. I use a [document filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) to ensure that only letters of the alphabet can be entered into the `JTextField`. The document filter also converts lower case letters to upper case.
3. I implement a [document listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) rather than a `KeyListener`. In the document listener, each time another letter is entered into the `JTextField`, I add another image to the list of images that need to be drawn.
4. As I wrote in my original answer, I override method `paintComponent()` and always draw the entire list of images.
5. I placed all the PNG images in the working directory, i.e. the value returned by `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. I did this only to make things easier for myself. You can put them anywhere you like. Just make sure you use the correct path to the files in your code.

Comment: Thank you! unfortunately my textfield keeps disappearing if I change Canvas to JPanel. And also without the textfield the I can still only see the current image.

Comment: Wow thank you so so much!! The explanation is very clear!